# how to clean the Signed-unsigned mix with relational warning in C?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  for(i = 1; (i+1) < argc; i+=2)
  {
      // do something here
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This code is based on the input for example: `command -name 1 -number 2,` that is why I need to have this: `(i+1) < argc;` in the loop, but I got the following lint warning:

```
Warning 574: Signed-unsigned mix with relational
```

what is the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that it's *exactly* the code you get that warning on? Because here there's no `unsigned` type, so that warning has no reason to be...

Comment: This is line at `574` ??

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No, it's warning number 574.

Comment: I am sure it is this line

Comment: The fix would be to provide the actual code, the actual warning including line number, and running lint on the actual code...Cut and paste please--NO TYPING!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is fine.

There's not a single unsigned variable or literal in the 9 lines you posted. You are doing something wrong. To find out what, lint those 9 lines exactly and provide us with lint's comments.